# How do I center a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I know that another person already asked this question. The answer is supposedly `frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);`, but when I try using this method, the `JFrame` ends up being on the bottom right corner of my screen. Why is this, and what else should I do to center my `JFrame`?

The first thing below is the code that I wrote (I was writing an Animalese translator by the way), and the second is a link to an image of what happens when I run the code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class AnimaleseTranslator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(220, 391, 220, 391));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));      
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setTitle("Animalese Translator");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);     
    }
}
```

[image: The JFrame is supposed to be in the center of the screen since I wrote the frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); line, but instead it is in the bottom right corner of the screen.]

Comment: Your frame looks centered...if the frame is 0x0. Try explicitly setting the `JFrame` size before setting the location.  See https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/jfc-swing/how-center-jframe-java-swing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `pack` before `setLocationRelativeTo`.

```
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: @XeroxMachine808 No problem.